# An analytical solution of the integral equation $ f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}} f(x+z) - f(x)\frac{C_2}{|z|^{1+\alpha}} dz $

Tags: integral-equations

How to solve for the f(x) in the **integral equation**?

$$
f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}} f(x+z) - f(x)\frac{C_2}{|z|^{1+\alpha}} dz \\
\alpha \in (1,2), C_2\text{ is a positive constant.} \\
\text{What is the definition of the function } f(x) \text{ in the given integral equation?}
$$

I have tried using **Taylor series method** to attempt to obtain some numerical solutions, as well as attempting to use **iterative methods** to derive some results, but without success.

I am unable to figure out on how to solve it.

Can someone please give some hints?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to look for nonzero solutions, otherwise $f \equiv 0$ is one if you just wanted existence.

Comment: Does this equation have an analytical solution or other numerical solutions? The problem is from a Russian textbook from 1964.